# How come $Ax\le b$ and $c^Tx\ge \alpha +\epsilon$ has NO nonnegative solution.

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Let $\alpha=c^Tx^*$ be the optimum value of the standard form of (LP)(= max $c^Tx$ subject to $Ax\le b$ and $x\ge0$ in $\mathbf{R^n}$)

Then we know:

$Ax\le b$ and $c^Tx\ge \alpha$ has a nonnegative solution.

But for any $\epsilon >0$ , the system

$Ax\le b$ and $c^Tx\ge \alpha +\epsilon$ has NO nonnegative solution.

I am studying a book about linear programming. Could you please explain the last statement.

Comment: Hmm, why was this put on hold? It may be a simple question but well-posed, and answered well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you could find a nonnegative $x$ such that $Ax \leq b$ and $c^T x \geq \alpha + \epsilon$, then $x^*$ would not be optimal for your LP.